# How do I block shots in FIFA 15 on PS4?

Tags: fifa-15

I would like to know the best way to defend against shots (especially using the Alternate 'Pro-Evo' like controls) - for some reason my friend seems to block 90% of my shots but I hardly seem to block any of his shots?

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about timing, holding X to run along and when a shot is about to be fired there is a timeframe where you have to press square to preform the block. (I use PES alt. controls too)

You can also hold r1 to call another defender to help you in your defence. I recommend trying the trainings, they're pretty usefull to improve your play. ;)

Good luck.

Comment: add me on psn network if you wish i'll give you a game u can train me lol

psn: zabius-uk